# Replacing nonzero elements of a matrix with corresponding elements of another matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

Given an n-by-n matrix A with elements equal to either 0 or 1, I want to replace only nonzero elements (A_ij)'s by (b_ij) and leave 0's intact where (b_ij)'s are themselves elements of another n-by-n matrix B. I do it as following

```
a[A_, n_] := 
 Table[If[A[[i, j]] == 1, A[[i, j]] = B[[i, j]], 0], {i, 
   n}, {j, n}]
```

Then by setting n=5, I get the following errors:

Part::partd: Part specification amat[[1,2]] is longer than depth of object.
Set::setps: {{0,1,0,0,0},{1,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0}} in the part assignment is not a symbol.

How can I get rid of these errors? Is there a better way to do this procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do: `newMatrix = A B`

Comment: well, if you mean the tensor product of A & B, it doesn't do the job.

Comment: @Bill what you wrote is slightly different than what I have written in my question. But yes, the code I wrote first gives me the mentioned errors but then generates what I want. The problem I guess is the way I call b_ij from matrix B by writing B[[i,j]].

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, define the matrices. Below I am doing $(5 \times 5)$ but the dimensions can easily be changed.

```
n = 5;
A = Table[RandomInteger[], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
B = Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
A // MatrixForm
B // MatrixForm
```

Then, you do the multiplication like so:

```
A B // MatrixForm
```

Comparing to the forms of the matrices `A` and `B` ,the result of the multiplication is the right answer.

Are there reasons that you want to use conditions? If, yes the following works fine:

```
(Table[If[A[[i, j]] == 0, 0, B[[i, j]]], {i, n}, {j, 
    n}]) // MatrixForm
```

and gives the same answer as the minimal approach which is the vanilla multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do in-place modification of `A` through a function call to `a`, then you have to tell `a` that you want to pass the matrix `A` by reference. You can do that by giving `a` the attribute `HoldFirst` (which in this context means call by reference for the first argument only).

So your function could look like this:

```
ClearAll[a];
SetAttributes[a, HoldFirst];
a[A_, B_] := Table[
   If[A[[i, j]] == 1, A[[i, j]] = B[[i, j]], 0],
   {i, Dimensions[A][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[A][[2]]}
   ];
```

Here is a simple test problem:

```
A = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {5, 5}]
B = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 5}]
a[A, B];
A
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
>
> {{2, 6, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2, 8}, {1, 1, 3, 10, 8}, {7, 6, 6, 8, 4}, {8, 9, 8, 2, 4}}
>
> {{0, 6, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 8}, {0, 6, 6, 8, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4}}

With Carl Woll's comment, you can also simply use this one:

```
ClearAll[a];
SetAttributes[a, HoldFirst];
a[A_, B_] := (A*=B);
```

If `A` is large and has only few nonzero entries, then you might want to consider to represent `A` as a `SparseArray`.